# How do I nest my <tr> from a script in a table

Tags: javascript, html, nested, html-table

I'm hoping this is a very easy question, but every single thing I can't think of wont work. The problem is that I have a table element, with a row of TH's and a couple of rows that are being imported from a js file. However, when I open the page, the actual table appears on the bottom of the page, and everything imported from the other files appears right above the table.

I think the issue is somewhere in my HTML, and not my Javascript files. The code is below. I also included a picture of what the result keeps looking like

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Backbone.js Web App</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />      
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <h1 id="frisbee_league">Frisbee league</h1>
            <article id="league">
                <nav class="actions">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="filter">
                            <label>Show:</label>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                        <form id="addTournament" action="#" class="form-2">
                            <h1>Add tournament</h1>
                            <label for="name">Name:</label><input id="name" placeholder="Tournament name" type="text" />
                            <label for="schedulingFormat">Format:</label><input id="schedulingFormat"  placeholder="Scheduling format" type="text" />
                            <div class="clearfix"><input type="submit" id="add" value="Add" /></div>
                        </form>
                    </ul>
                </nav>


                            <table id="leagues">
                <tr>
                    <th>Team</th>
                    <th>Format</th>
                    <th>W</th>
                    <th>L</th>
                    <th>Sets won</th>
                    <th>Sets lost</th>
                    <th>Set Difference</th>
                    <th>Points won</th>
                    <th>Points lost</th>
                    <th>Points Difference</th>
                </tr>
                <div class="tournaments"></div>

            </table>

        </article>

     </div>

        <script id="tournamentTemplate" type ="text/template">
                    <td><%= name %></td>
                    <td><%= schedulingFormat %></td>
                    <td><%= Win %></td>
                    <td><%= Lost %></td>
                    <td><%= Sw %></td>
                    <td><%= Sl %></td>
                    <td><%= Sd %></td>
                    <td><%= Pw %></td>
                    <td><%= Pl %></td>
                    <td><%= Pd %></td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></td>
        </script>



        <!-- Libraries -->
        <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/json2.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/underscore-min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/backbone-min.js"></script>

        <!-- Application -->
        <script src="js/app/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app/models/tournamentModel.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app/collections/leagueCollection.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app/views/tournamentView.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app/views/leagueView.js"></script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can we see your JavaScript, specifically where the rows are appended or prepended or inserted.

Comment: Have you tried using <tbody id="tournaments"></tbody>? A <div> isn't a valid child for a <table>.

Comment: Ronaan, I love you. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script id="tournamentsTemplate" type ="text/template">
          <tr>
                <td><%= name %></td>
                <td><%= schedulingFormat %></td>
                <td><%= Win %></td>
                <td><%= Lost %></td>
                <td><%= Sw %></td>
                <td><%= Sl %></td>
                <td><%= Sd %></td>
                <td><%= Pw %></td>
                <td><%= Pl %></td>
                <td><%= Pd %></td>
                <td><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></td>
          </tr>
    </script>
```

Comment: As of [the linked image in the question](http://i.imgur.com/J0iLh.png) there are already `TR`'s, because otherwise the browser would present all the cells next to each other, instead of single lines of table cells. @Max V Z They are just not added to the `table#leagues` but to the `div.tournaments`. It's hard to say what's going on there, without having a look on the JS involved.